# Sharepoint Online - retrieve Subfolder Items using CSOM and "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold"

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I'm trying to download all items from a Subfolder in my Site Library. Unfortunately I hit the "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold" exception.

Here my code:

```
using (var authenticationManager = new ShpAuthenticationManager()) using (var context = authenticationManager.GetContext(site, userName, password)) {
Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(web.Lists);
context.Load(web, wb => wb.ServerRelativeUrl);
context.ExecuteQuery();

List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Uploads");
context.Load(list);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(subfolderUrl);
context.Load(folder);
context.ExecuteQuery();

ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;
var page = 1;

do
{
    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = @"
<View Scope='Recursive'>
    <Query>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields>
    <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
</View>";
    query.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
    query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;

    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
    context.Load(items);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    position = items.ListItemCollectionPosition;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{items.ListItemCollectionPosition.PagingInfo}][{page}] {item.Id}: {item["Title"]}");
    }
    page++;
} while (position != null);
```

It throws the Threshold Exception even if the subfolder contains only 10 items. When I remove this line

```
    query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
```

no error occurs but I receive all items from the whole library, not the specific subfolder.